# Who is "The man" here?

Tags: numbers

In Numbers 5:31 (NASB)

> The man, moreover, will be free of guilt, but that woman shall bear the consequences of her guilt.’”

Who is "The man" referenced here? The husband or the one the wife slept with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see the context:

> Numbers5:29 ‘This is the law of jealousy: when a wife, who is under the authority of her **husband**, goes astray and defiles herself, 30or when an attitude of jealousy comes over a **man** and **he** is jealous of **his** wife, **he** shall then have the woman stand before the LORD, and the priest shall apply all of this law to her. 31The **man**, moreover, will be free of guilt, but that woman shall bear the consequences of her guilt.’”

All the pronouns reference the husband. There is no explicit mention of the illicit one whom the wife slept with.

The syntax and the semantics both point to the husband.